# Geographical filter on multiple fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, geo

I have multiple geo_point fields representing a flight, I want to filter geographically on at least one of the points.

Is there a solution that without a *bool or* clause?

index mapping:

```
    "Flight":{
                "properties":{
                    ...
                    "point_src":{"type":"geo_point"},
                    "point_dest":{"type":"geo_point"},
                    ...
                }
            }
```

sample documents:

```
{
          "point_dest": [
            {
              "lat": 50.110922,
              "lon": 8.682127
            }
          ],
          "point_src": [
            {
              "lat": 33.893791,
              "lon": 35.501777
            }
          ]
      }
```

Comment: can you add one sample document ?

Comment: @user3775217 added one

Answer (score 0):

The reason why asked you for excat document is to find out how many geo_points you can have to match on. I looks like currently you have only two geo_points so you can do the following query. [Geo_distance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html) query and a should boolean

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "bool": {
                    "filter": {
                        "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "20000000km",
                    "point_src" : {
                        "lat" : 40,
                        "lon" : -70
                    }
                }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": {
                        "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "200km",
                    "point_dest" : {
                        "lat" : 40,
                        "lon" : -70
                    }
                }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Note - Again if you would have multiple geo_points in your document instead of these two. I would have suggested you to have a nested_type for locations with each item in the locations of the type geo_point and you could easily do the [nested_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) which will behave the same as above, just one match from any of the nested values would have to return the document.

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {}
    },
    "mappings": {
        "product": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties": {
                "locations": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "point": {
                            "type": "geo_point"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```